# or inside case statement not running in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I m having a query in which inside a case statement i have put a or statement.

The or statement is not running for some reason.

The example -

```
 update shouts set visibility=(case when (visibility = null or visibility =1) 
 then 2 else 1 end) where shout_id = 788
```

Now when visibility is null it should update 2 while for no known reason it is updating the field to 1.

Comment: Try `visibility IS null`

Comment: yup somtimes confusing updates should be = null and queries should be `is null`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IS` operator when comparing with `NULL`. Because comparing something with `NULL` will lead to *unknown* when using the normal operators, which is not *true*.

```
update shouts 
set visibility = case when visibility IS null or visibility = 1
                      then 2 
                      else 1 
                 end
where shout_id = 788
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that you can simplify the logic:

```
update shouts
    set visibility = (case when visibility <> 1 then 1 else 2 end) 
    where shout_id = 788;
```

Or even:

```
update shouts
    set visibility = 2 - (visibility <> 1) 
    where shout_id = 788;
```

Juergen's is the right solution to the particular problem, though.

Comment: appreciate the first code. For second one there's a confusion, when the visibility is 2 the 2-2 = 0 and when the visibility is null then 2-null will give 2.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya . . . The expression `visibility <> 1` is a boolean expression.  When true, it has the value of `1`, when false it is treated as `0`.